# How to create game menu ui (i.e. buttons, scroll views) with Scene Kit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I would like to create game menus for my Scene Kit game, such as a title screen and pause menu, but I'm struggling with how to do it. I don't think rendering the menu in 3d space, and using a UITapGestureRecognizer is the best way.

Any insight on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer will depend on what you are trying to create. You can mix Scene Kit and Sprite Kit, and you can also have a separate menu using stylized UIKit components

Comment: Yeah, I've done some more looking around, and found the Bananas apple demo, this seems to use Scene Kit and Sprite Kit, as you've suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements for a title screen, pause and even HUD elements, UIKit could work. I would not recommend UIKit if you need any fancy stuff like shaders, particle effects or a lot of heavy animations. In that case I would go with Sprite Kit as suggested by David Rönnqvist.

But if your needs are menu screens, simple HUD elements, dialogs etc. there are no problems too use UIKit with any needed custom views, and just treat the SCNView like any other UIKit view. The up side is of course that UIKit does a great job for common UI tasks and user interaction, and is very easy and simple to use. Sprite Kit can some times feel a bit heavy for UI in my opinion.

Comment: What would be the best way to manage different view controllers and go between them? Would it make sense to use a navigation controller, because currently I am just creating new view controllers and presenting them which is causing memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an SCNScene and set up hit testing. 
You can use the SceneKit Scene Builder to make it look just the way you want; 
no need to use tap gestures. 
This is what I usually do for SceneKit menus.